# Universal IL Assember

Tags: architecture, assembly

I'm looking for an universal assembler for custom microcode architectures. Does anyone know of an (open source) application that can take an ASM file, and an architecture definition file of some kind, and emit binary opcodes?

Comment: perhaps LLVM is an option - see http://llvm.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools like that. The ones I know about:

1. GNU's [CGEN](http://sourceware.org/cgen/), used for a couple of archs in binutils.
2. [ArchC Assembler Generator](http://archc.sourceforge.net/page30.html).
3. Various academic tools using Sim-nML language, see e.g. [Processor Models for Retargetable Tools](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/moona/papers/rsp2000.pdf)